# How do I find tabbed lines in text file in Java?

Tags: java, file, tabs

I have text files that are laid out like the following.

```
Product Name
    HP Compaq Elite 8300 CMT
```

(HP Compaq Elite 8300 CMT is on its own line and has one tab space in front of it)

I am trying to find a way to read line by line and remove lines starting with the tab. First I am turning the file into a string list:

```
public static List<String> readFile2(File file) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    //Construct BufferedReader from InputStreamReader
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(br.readLine());
    }

    br.close();
    return list;
}
```

and I have tried many different statements in a loop when reading the list but the correct lines are not returned:

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)

    {
        if(list.get(i).indexOf("\u0009")>-1 || list.get(i).contains("\u0009") || list.get(i).indexOf((char)9)>-1 || list.get(i).startsWith(" ") || list.get(i).startsWith("\t"))
        {
        list.remove(i);
        }
    }
```

any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java's [`String` class has a `startsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-) method that allows you to test if the String starts with a given prefix or not. You can use this to identify lines that start with a tab character. By using this, you can test the line you just read out of the buffer and not add it to your list int he first place.

```
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if(!line.startsWith("\u0009")) {
        list.add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just implemented this and tested it and it returns every line.

Comment: Are you sure your data really starts with a single tab?

Comment: The first character is unicode 9, which I believe is tab. I can't show a picture because I am new here.

Comment: Awesome. Glad we got that sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have suggested (better<sup>1</sup>) alternative approaches that avoid putting the matched lines into the list in the first place.

Here's an explanation of why your version doesn't work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (/* match line */) {
        list.remove(i);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when you remove the ith list element, all elements at larger indexes get "renumbered"; e.g. `list.get(i + 1)` becomes `list.get(i)` and so on.

But the next thing you do is to increment `i`.  So ... in effect ... when you remove an element, the next element doesn't get checked.

Here is a correct way to do it:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < list.size()) {
    if (/* match line */) {
        list.remove(i);
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Note that you DON'T increment `i` if you removed the `i`th element.

---

For the record, any one of those tests that you used was sufficient to match a line containing a TAB.  Writing the same test lots of different ways did not help.  There is a lesson in that for you ...

---

<sup>1 - It is simpler (less code), and also significantly more efficient in you are processing a large file.  Removing an element from an arbitrary position in an `ArrayList` is an `O(N)` operation.</sup>